# CSS is preventing from collapsing my DIV

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have Jquery that when you click the h3 tag it will hide that div. The problem that I have is that there is that white-space:pre is preventing me for collapsing the div. I been going crazy trying to figure out, but I not able to find the solution.

Here is my HTML Code:

```
<!-- first file -->
      <div class="file_wrapper">
        <h2>Previous Version of Pre.report.txt</h2>
        <div class="file_inner">
        <ol class="ol_counter">
<div  style="width: 100%" class="block1"><h3> Result </h3>
<li>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++</li>
<li></li>
<li>##############################################################################</li>
<li># Test 1. </li>
<li># Test 2. </li>
<li># Test 3. </li>
<li># Test 4. </li>
<li># Test 5. </li>
<li>##############################################################################</li>
            </div>
<div  style="width: 100%" class="block2"><h3> Result </h3>
<li>+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++</li>
<li></li>
<li>##############################################################################</li>
<li># Test 1. </li>
<li># Test 2. </li>
<li># Test 3. </li>
<li># Test 4. </li>
<li># Test 5. </li>
<li>##############################################################################</li>
            </div>
<div  style="width: 100%" class="block3"><h3> Result </h3>
<li>++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++</li>
<li></li>
<li>##############################################################################</li>
<li># Test 1. </li>
<li># Test 2. </li>
<li># Test 3. </li>
<li># Test 4. </li>
<li># Test 5. </li>
<li>##############################################################################</li>
            </div>                </div>                                                                                                    
              </div>
              </div>
```

The problem is on the .file_wrapper {white-space: pre;}

If I removed it the text will not hold the format.

I would like something like this: 
[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LZ99t/6/)

And here is my code:[demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/y98R5/1)

Thanks in advance and just let you know that I'm a pro on css or html. I'm just formating a perl script output to look nice on html.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. `<li>` is the only possible child for an `<ol>` element. You have a lot of div, h3 ecc in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to keep the html as it is, here is a css solution that should fit your needs.

I modified on your fiddle :

1. removed `white-space: pre;` on `.file_wraper`
2. changed `margin-left` to `0` on `.file_wrapper h2`
3. set `margin:0;` on `li`
4. set `margin: 0 0 0px 30px;` on `.file_wrapper h3`

See this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/y98R5/36/)**

Comment: The list number needs to continue. In this code The number will go back to 1 three times. The count should be from 1 to 27.